# Why do METARs report wind relative to true north rather than magnetic?

Tags: runways, wind, metar, magnetic-variation

Why **isn't** the wind in a METAR given in magnetic heading, to match the runway numbers? Especially for areas where there is a double-digit magnetic declination.

Secondary/optional question: does the ATIS broadcast in true or magnetic?

Example: [BGGH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuuk_Airport) 281550Z 36004KT (an airport in Greenland, var 27.55°W).

[image]

Source: Wikipedia ([click for full image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/World_Magnetic_Declination_2015.pdf/page1-1280px-World_Magnetic_Declination_2015.pdf.jpg))

Comment: METARs are always true, regardless of magnetic variation; ATIS is always magentic (except for some automated ones I think? but I'm not 100% sure on that)

Comment: @falstro I was about to concoct a question as to why polar runways get a special treatment after reading your first comment, phew.

Comment: It looks to me like you're combining two different questions here. First, why do METARs use true instead of magnetic (to match runway headings, like ATIS does)? That's [the case everywhere](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/60/62), not just in certain areas. Second, are ATIS winds still given as magnetic in (polar) regions where magnetic headings may be unreliable? If that's an accurate summary then you might consider splitting your question to get better answers on each point.

Comment: @Pondlife Only one question, why **isn't** the wind in a METAR given in magnetic heading (in a place like Greenland), to match the runway numbers? The other is just me thinking out loud, I'll clarify it.

Comment: @ymb1 runways *do* get special treatment in areas where magnetic compasses are unreliable (i.e. close to the pole). [So do VORs by they way](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/351/how-are-vors-oriented-near-the-magnetic-poles). I just realized that wasn't the question, and BGGH is not one of those airports.

Comment: @mins surface winds are pretty much only used for takeoff and landing (and the ATIS is always magnetic).

Comment: @ymb1 I updated the question to just talk about METARs in general, since this is not limited to high magnetic variation (much of the US has double digit magnetic variation). Revert if you feel it's not what you're asking.

Comment: @falstro it's good thanks, I just expanded it to highlight your comment in the question.

Comment: @ymb1 I deleted that comment.  I misread the other answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Metars are used by more groups than just aviation.  In the U.S. it is official weather for the National Weather Service.  It is easier to graph winds in relation to true north than have them in shown in magnetic north.  The graph wouldn't make much sense.

Spoken winds are in magnetic because they are specific to aviation and that is what pilots care about.